# bash colours: OS X vs Linux

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I have a very simple script to colorize Maven output in bash. It works great under Linux, but not at all under OS X

```
# Colorize maven output
# Thanks to https://github.com/builddoctor/maven-antsy-color

alias maven="command mvn"
function color_maven() {
    local BLUE="\x1b[0;34m"
    local RED="\x1b[0;31m"
    local GREEN="\x1b[0;32m"
    local YELLOW="\x1b[1;33m"
    local WHITE="\x1b[1;37m"
    local LIGHT_RED="\x1b[1;31m"
    local LIGHT_GREEN="\x1b[1;32m"
    local LIGHT_BLUE="\x1b[1;34m"
    local LIGHT_CYAN="\x1b[1;36m"
    local NO_COLOUR="\x1b[0m"
    maven $* | sed \
        -e "s/Tests run: \([^,]*\), Failures: \([^,]*\), Errors: \([^,]*\), Skipped: \([^,]*\)/${LIGHT_GREEN}Tests run: \1$NO_COLOUR, Failures: $RED\2$NO_COLOUR, Errors: $YELLOW\3$NO_COLOUR, Skipped: $LIGHT_BLUE\4$NO_COLOUR/g" \
        -e "s/\(\[\{0,1\}WARN\(ING\)\{0,1\}\]\{0,1\}.*\)/$YELLOW\1$NO_COLOUR/g" \
        -e "s/\(\[ERROR\].*\)/$RED\1$NO_COLOUR/g" \
        -e "s/\(\(BUILD \)\{0,1\}FAILURE.*\)/$RED\1$NO_COLOUR/g" \
        -e "s/\(\(BUILD \)\{0,1\}SUCCESS.*\)/$LIGHT_GREEN\1$NO_COLOUR/g" \
        -e "s/\(\[INFO\].*\)/$GREEN\1$NO_COLOUR/g"

        MAVEN_STATUS=$PIPESTATUS

        return $MAVEN_STATUS
}
```

Under OSX this is how my output is being displayed:

```
x1b[0;32m[INFO] Scanning for projects...x1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] -----------------------------------------------x1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] x1B[0;31mBUILD FAILUREx1b[0mx1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] -----------------------------------------------x1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] Total time: 0.097 sx1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-19T20:35:12+02:00x1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/123Mx1b[0m
x1b[0;32m[INFO] -----------------------------------------------x1b[0m
```

I assume it is a problem with the `\x1b` control sequence. I have also tried `\[\033` and `\033` in its place, with the same broken result.

My prompt is also colorized and works under Linux and OSX, it is defined like this:

```
export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;35m\]\w\[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;31m\]\$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;35m\]$\[\033[0m\] "
```

So the question is, what is the deal with OSX? What do I need to do to get colors to work properly?

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd say it's a problem with the Mac terminal emulator rather than OSX. If you try a different terminal emulator that recognises those escape sequences you might have more luck, or your current terminal emulator might recognise different escape sequences.

Comment: Can you see any colors, from any program, on your terminal?

Comment: yes I can... I'll update the question

Comment: Is the problem perhaps how `sed` interprets the values?

Comment: Is there a change after `tput setaf 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU version of `sed` you'll find on Linux is a bit different from the version on OS X. The difference you're running into is that the GNU version interprets hex escapes (e.g. `\x1b` -> an ASCII ESC character) and translates them into the corresponding characters (in this case the escape character), while the OS X version doesn't.

Fortunately, there's a simple solution: rather than counting on `sed` to do the escape interpretation, tell `bash` to do it for you:

```
local BLUE=$'\x1b[0;34m'
local RED=$'\x1b[0;31m'
...etc
```

Bash's `$'...'` quote format does escape interpretation, so when you use those variables in the `sed` command, they've already been interpreted and get substituted as you expect.

Note that this same script should work fine on Linux as well.